# Indoor 3D explorable map - help with visualization

Tags: 3d, web

I've made a 3D map of a building with SketchUp. My next step should be to visualize it on a browser (which is actually possible), but I would like to create some clickable areas to trigger the visualization of a spherical photo of the inside.

I know it's not exactly a GIS issue but I hope to be forgiven.

Comment: it seems to me you are looking for a code snipped to implement your 3d building map into a webgis. while *imho* this is ontopic, you are expected to provide some code to show your current progress and for ppl to be able to help you

Comment: well...this has not much more in common with GIS than the term 'map'. there are pros and devs for webgl and the mighty three.js library over at stack overflow!